# Can't locate object method "***" via package "Apache2::RequestRec"

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl, vhosts

i'm trying to get mod_perl working on my apache installation in order to use perlhandler.

i first tryied in a subdirectory of my domain with this virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ***.fr.cr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/aw
    <Directory /var/www/aw/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    PerlModule test2::Rules2
    alias /perl2/ /usr/lib/perl5/test2/
    <Location /perl2/>
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            SetHandler perl-script
            PerlHandler test2::Rules2
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aw.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aw.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And here, it is working fine when i go to ***.fr.cr/perl2/

But, when i try to directoly do it to the root of my domain, with this virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ***.fr.cr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/aw
    <Directory /var/www/aw/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    PerlModule aw::main
    alias / /usr/lib/perl5/aw/
    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            SetHandler perl-script
            PerlHandler aw::main
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aw.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aw.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

i got error 500, and the apache log has this line :

```
Can't locate object method "content_type" via package "Apache2::RequestRec" at /usr/lib/perl5/aw/main.pm line 6.\n
```

The strange thing is i tested with 2 codes

one missing the "print" package and one missing the "content_type" package, and the first one has a "content_type", but the error is later in the code.

I guess i'm missing something with my virtual host, because it works in one case, and not in the other with the same code.

Thanks!

edit : the code :
not working :

```
package aw::main;
use Apache2::Const qw(:common);

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;
    $r->content_type("text/plain");
    $r->print("mod_perl rules!\n");
    return OK;
}
1;
```

and working :

```
package test2::Rules2;
use Apache2::Const qw(:common);

sub handler {
my $r = shift;
$r->content_type("text/plain");
$r->print("mod_perl rules!\n");
return OK;
}
1;
```

Comment: The most likely conclusion is that there's a bug in aw::main that's not in test2::Rules2.

Comment: I copy / pasted the code. I'll try to copy the file and rename it

Comment: Then I was right. For starters, your `package` declaration is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm editing my post to add the codes

Comment: Try adding `use Apache2::RequestRec;`? Shouldn't have to, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Still not working, but it changed the missing from "content_type" to "print"

Comment: I know it's a bit old, but the missing package was Apache2::RequestIO

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with the same problem and I think I've found the answer:

When you call an object method in Perl, e.g. myinstance->themethod(arg1) then themethod gets the name of the class (package) as the first parameter and the first argument as the second parameter.  If you call a method as a static method, e.g. class::method(arg1) then the first parameter the subroutine gets is the first argument.  Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Calling as an object method:\n";
fish->chips('lettuce');
print "Calling as a static method:\n";
fish::chips('lettuce');

{package fish;

sub chips {
  my $x=shift;
  my $y=shift;

  print "\$x is $x and \$y is $y\n";
  }
}
```

and the output of that is:

```
Calling as an object method:
$x is fish and $y is lettuce
Calling as a static method:
$x is lettuce and $y is
```

mod_perl is calling your handler as an object method.  It's taking the package name as the first parameter.  If you add a `shift` and throw away the first parameter before you `shift` the second parameter then your `$r` will probably be the request object you're looking for.

After looking at my Apache conf file again I realize that I had given the handler directive as `PerlResponseHandler Fish->chips` instead of `PerlResponseHandler Fish::chips`.  I had some trouble with mod_perl in finding the handler I wanted to use.  When I specified Fish and named the handler `sub handler {...` then mod_perl couldn't find it.  Likewise, when I specified the handler name, as in `Fish::handler` (or, as I renamed it) `Fish::chips` then Apache would look for a file named `chips.pm` in a directory named `Fish`.

I don't know if this is an actual bug in the way mod_perl is parsing or resolving handler names, but at the least it's very brittle behaviour.  Unless I'm missing something here, and if I am I hope someone can point it out.

I hope that helps.